# Execute cloud build from script in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, build-process

Want to make cloud build functionality in Unity.
How can I do it in Unity from script(in EditorWindow)?
Update: Found Pre- and post-export methods, but still can't find the way to execute cloud build...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to execute a cloud build programmatically is to use Unity's Cloud Build API.

The API documentation is [available here](https://build-api.cloud.unity3d.com/docs/1.0.0/index.html), and the build command itself is [here](https://build-api.cloud.unity3d.com/docs/1.0.0/index.html#operation--orgs--orgid--projects--projectid--buildtargets--buildtargetid--builds-post)

Their example for making the call via curl is

```
curl
  -X POST
  -d '{"clean": true, "delay": 30}'
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  -H "Authorization: Basic [YOUR API KEY]"
  https://build-api.cloud.unity3d.com/api/v1/orgs/{orgid}/projects/{projectid}/buildtargets/{buildtargetid}/builds
```

Making web service calls from Unity is probably a separate question, but has ample documentation online.

[`BuildPipeline`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.html) doesn't seem to offer cloud functionality, yet.

[`CloudProjectSettings`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CloudProjectSettings.html) may streamline your efforts a bit, if you're trying to kick off a build for the currently open project.

Comment: and what about BuildSettings? is Unity sending them from BuildSettings into cloud? and can you share some example of "but has ample documentation online"? All I want to do is generate cloud build from UnityEdor in my custom EditorWindow.

Comment: As far as I know Unity doesn't provide a special programmatic way to access cloud build services from within Unity, so there isn't a simple "All I want to do..." approach. BuildSettings I believe are handled via the [`buildtargets`](https://build-api.cloud.unity3d.com/docs/1.0.0/index.html#operation--orgs--orgid--projects--projectid--buildtargets-post) endpoint. By documentation I mean that it's the same as any other webservice call you might make from Unity, i.e., google 'unity webservice call' and dig around. I don't have an active cloud build account so I can't offer sample code, sorry.